# Spark - Principal Component Analysis - PCA requires a number of principal components k >= 1 but was given 0

Tags: apache-spark-mllib, pca

I'm trying to reduce my dimensionality (I've 120 columns) for that I want to apply PCA method:

```
val data = sc.textFile("data")

val header = data.first

val rows = data.filter(l => l != header)

import org.apache.spark.mllib.feature.PCA
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vectors
import org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.{LabeledPoint, LinearRegressionWithSGD}

val data = rows.map { line =>
  val parts = line.split(';')
  LabeledPoint(parts(0).toDouble, Vectors.dense(parts(1).split(';').map(_.toDouble)))
}.cache()

val splits = data.randomSplit(Array(0.9, 0.1), seed = 11L)
val training = splits(0).cache()
val test = splits(1)

val pca = new PCA(training.first().features.size / 2).fit(data.map(_.features))
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: PCA requires a number of principal components k >= 1 but was given 0
    at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:233)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.feature.PCA.<init>(PCA.scala:33)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:59)
```

Anyone have an idea why I'm having this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You're splitting on ';' to obtain `parts`, and then in the construction of the `LabeledPoint` you're splitting `parts` on ';' again. I suspect that the resulting `Vector` has length 1, so when you compute `training.first().features.size/2` you get 0.

Comment: I already put the seconds LABELEDPOINT uisng (" ") and I've this vectors:data: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.LabeledPoint] = MapPartitionsRDD[3] at map at <console>:40
But I'm still getting the same issue